# Pass parameter to collection's type

Tags: c#

What would be a simple way to pass a parameter to a class constructor when it's a collection of that class?

I'm thinking I need to derive from ObservableCollection to accommodate the parameter, but not sure what the best way is to do that.

```
// constructor
class MyClass(object myParam)
{ 
   // do something here
}

// usage

Items = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();  // How do I pass myParam?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a collection does not allocate any objects of that class. When you do `Items.Add(new MyClass(<argument>)` pass the arguments at that point.

Answer (score 1):

It possible in the following ways

```cs
// class
class MyClass
{
    // constructor
    public MyClass(object myParam)
    {

    }
}

// make a object
object param = new object();

// pass param
var Items = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(){new MyClass(param)};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to write this:

```
public MyClass(MyClass[] myParam)
{ 
   // do something here
}
```

The code of a class can use the class itself as a type. In native C++ you had to provide a prototype to do that, but by the time .NET came around the compilers were able to figure that part out.

If MyClass is a generic collection, this would be the code:

```
class MyClassCollection : List<MyClass>{
  public MyClass(MyClass myParam){
    // do something here
  }
}
```

I have no idea why you think you that - of all the collection classes - you need to derive from ObservableCollection. You can derive from it, but there is nothing forcing you to pick it.